# Mathpsfrag: failed setup at MathPSfragConfigurationTest (UnPSfrag) line (Windows 8)

Tags: packages, interoperability, windows

I'm trying to follow the documentation on how to get mathpsfrag set up on Windows 8 (64-bit). It failed at the line

```
If[MathPSfragConfigurationTest[] === True, okPrint["Passed"], errorPrint["Failed"]];
```

saying that it found latex and dvips but not ghostscript. So then I found the paths for latex.exe, dvips.exe, and gswin64c.exe and put them into the `UnPSfrag` part as so:

```
SetOptions[UnPSfrag,
    GhostscriptExecutable -> "C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.15\\bin\\gswin64c",
    LaTeXExecutable ->    "C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\latex",
    DvipsExecutable ->    "C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\dvips"]; 
If[MathPSfragConfigurationTest[] === True, okPrint["Passed"], errorPrint["Failed"]];
```

I also tried with .exe at the ends of the names, and with .exe at just the end of the gswin64c one (as in the example in that same file -- not really sure why their example does that). When I do this, now it won't even find latex! The only thing I can think of is maybe the folders have admin-only privileges or something weird?

Comment: Could you link to the documentation of mathpsfrag or MathPSfragConfigurationTest? I can't find it in the built-in documentation. Are you using some kind of external party package?

Comment: I guess that would have been helpful. =P
http://wwwth.mpp.mpg.de/members/jgrosse/mathpsfrag/files/manual.pdf specifically sections 3.2 and 5.4

Comment: Also the files are just from their main site: http://wwwth.mpp.mpg.de/members/jgrosse/mathpsfrag/ MathPSfrag 2 (zip) under the Download section

Comment: You might be interested in [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) which seems to be able to do similar things, but looks simpler.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries thanks for the idea. It looks nice, but it says it requires Mathematica 10 and I'm currently using 9 so maybe not feasible for me atm.

Comment: @Hanmyo Do you have the opportunity to upgrade to Mathematica 10?  It is true that MaTeX requires Mathematica 10.  It uses the new [process control functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DirectControlOfExternalProcesses.html) which would be just too much trouble to do with only `Run` (which is also available in 9).  Version 10 is a pretty big upgrade, with many useful new features.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with the installation process for a third-party package.

Comment: @MarcoB Personally I disagree with closing this ... it is a Mathematica package, so the question is directly related to Mathematica.  Whether a package is made by WRI or someone else shouldn't matter.  I do agree that OP is more likely to get a useful response if he contacts the package author directly.  But I *want* this sort of question to be on-topic.  If the question does get closed, I'll make a meta post so the community can formally decide whether this is a valid close reason (for similar future cases).

Comment: @Szabolcs I see your point. I think it would be an excellent idea to have the meta discussion anyway, independently of whether this question will be closed. Questions like these do crop up regularly. It has been my impression that they typically don't receive much attention, so developing a community-approved approach to helping the asker would be great.

Comment: @MarcoB OK, I'll make a post later.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use MathPSFrag on Windows system the file paths should be in correct "full path" form (explicit extra quoting with "\"fullpath\"" worked for me):

```
SetOptions[UnPSfrag, 
"LaTeXExecutable" -> "\"c:\\Latex\\MikTexPortable\\miktex\\bin\\latex.exe\"", 
"DvipsExecutable" -> "\"c:\\Latex\\MikTexPortable\\miktex\\bin\\dvips.exe\"", 
"GhostscriptExecutable" -> "\"c:\\Latex\\GsViewPortable\\gs8.64\\bin\\gswin32c.exe\""]
```