# Where can I obtain the package Mathpsfrag?

Tags: export, latex

Documentation for mathpsfrag can be found here:

- https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.2175
- http://www.tug.org/tugboat/tb29-1/tb91grosse.pdf

However, the authors webpage recorded on [http://packagedata.net](http://packagedata.net/index.php/links/search/183/MathPSfrag)

> http://wwwth.mpp.mpg.de/members/jgrosse/mathpsfrag/

is offline.

Does anyone know an alternative source?

Comment: A few months ago it was still live ... perhaps try to contact the author?  If you can't find it, you may be able to use MaTeX instead of MathPSFrag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [link](https://wwwth.mpp.mpg.de/members/jgrosse/mathpsfrag/) was updated after request!

For the convenience I have reuploaded the main file to the Google Drive:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k1-SkH0mrA__gF68JThGyKtsMkVj3Neg

In Windows the full paths to the MathPSFrag Options are recommended ([see](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/221633/57534)).

MathPSFrag is recommended to use with [CustomTicks package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5599/),
that copy of which is also uploaded to the Drive:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FsyZj2zobTbeaEaIGwxUkii-dCCYTcph

Comment: The home of CustomTicks is here: https://scidraw.nd.edu/

Comment: May I encourage you to also set up a GitHub or Bitbucket (or whatever your preferred source management service) account, and put up the software there? It would surely be more reliable than Google Drive in the long run.

Comment: I agree with you, but I encourage the author of the package do it himself since I am not the author of this package and I am not going to continue its development (as it does not work in mathematica > 10 version). I will only keep the copy of files in Google Drive for everyone interested as long as I can. The Customticks package is saved also only for convenience, as this version is recommended to use with MathPSFrag.